# Python islice class is not working as expected

Tags: python, generator, python-itertools

I am writing a function that divides a list into (almost) equal 'n' distributions. I want this function to return a generator, but there appears to be an issue with yielding a generator. The function works just fine with iterables. Take a look at this snippet:

```
import itertools


def divide_list(array, n, gen_length=None):
    """
    :param array: some iterable that you wish to divide
    :param n: the number of lists you would like to return
    :param gen_length: The length of the generator if array is a generator. Not necessary for lists and tuples.
    :return: a generator of the divided list

    Example:
    In: list(divide_list([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 4))
    Out: [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7], [8, 9]]
    """
    if isinstance(array, (list, tuple)):
        floor, rem = divmod(len(array), n)

        items_index = (0, floor)
        for _ in range(n):
            prev, next_ = items_index[0], items_index[1] + 1 if rem > 0 else items_index[1]
            yield array[prev:next_]
            items_index = (next_, next_ + floor)
            rem -= 1
    else:
        floor, rem = divmod(gen_length, n)

        items_index = (0, floor)
        for _ in range(n):
            prev, next_ = items_index[0], items_index[1] + 1 if rem > 0 else items_index[1]
            yield itertools.islice(array, prev, next_)
            items_index = (next_, next_ + floor)
            rem -= 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    array_ = iter([12, 7, 9, 31, 13, 11, 7, 3])

    print('Generator:')
    print('----------')
    for value in divide_list(array_, 3, gen_length=8):
        print(list(value))

    print('')
    array_ = [12, 7, 9, 31, 13, 11, 7, 3]

    print('List:')
    print('-----')
    for value in divide_list(array_, 3):
        print(value)
```

Here is the ouput:

```
Generator:
----------
[12, 7, 9]
[7, 3]
[]

List:
-----
[12, 7, 9]
[31, 13, 11]
[7, 3]
```

Why is the last generator exhausted? Sometimes, it exhausts the last two generators.

Comment: Well you tell `islice` to skip the next `prev` elements.

Comment: Could you elaborate or change my code up? I want `islice` to skip up to `prev` and go to `next_` then do the same thing over again until it reaches the end of the list. @KellyBundy

Comment: "I want islice to skip up to `prev`" - No you don't. What you think you want to skip is already sliced off of the iterator. You don't want to skip any.

Comment: You're saying that I am trying to `yield` part of the generator that I have sliced off, but I'm not. This example is equivalent to calling the array at these indices: ((0, 3), (3, 6), (6, 8)) @KellyBundy

Comment: No, that's rather the opposite of what I'm saying. What I'm saying is that you forget that you already have sliced elements off, so you shouldn't try to additionally skip them. The second of those commands shouldn't use `3, 6` but `0, 3`.

Comment: Ohhhh I see. It shifts the list back to the front. This should be an easy fix. Thank you @KellyBundy

Comment: @GabeMorris yes, because the *iterator* you are handling has already advanced. Basically, with the sequence case (list, tuple) you give it particular indices, in the case of `islice`, you give it a *length* instead, starting at `0`, if you start above zero, it *skips those elements*. Note, you probably want `yield list(itertools.islice(...))` to behave the same way as the array version

Comment: BTW, there's no need to handle these two cases separately. You can just treat everything as an iterator.

Answer (score 3):

The explanation as to why this isn't working is because you are using `islice` to *skip elements* when you provided it a non-zero starting point. The key issue here is that you are supposed to *advance the iterator by an amount*, not skipping any at each yield. This is different than the sequence case, where you give it explicit indices for each case.

However, note, *you don't need to handle these cases differently*. Here's a super simple approach that handles both cases - the key is to *always* use an iterator:

```
def divide(iterable, n, length=None):
    if length is None:
        length = len(iterable)
    it = iter(iterable)
    floor, rem = divmod(length, n)
    while result := list(islice(it, floor + bool(rem))):
        yield result
        rem = max(rem - 1, 0)
```

In the REPL:

```
>>> from itertools import islice
>>> def divide(iterable, n, length=None):
...     if length is None:
...         length = len(iterable)
...     it = iter(iterable)
...     floor, rem = divmod(length, n)
...     while result := list(islice(it, floor + bool(rem))):
...         yield result
...         rem = max(rem - 1, 0)
...
>>> list(divide([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 4))
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7], [8, 9]]
>>> list(divide(iter([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]), 4, length=9))
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7], [8, 9]]
```

Comment: This is a far better way of doing this.

Comment: Hmm, actually still might not be right. Parameter `n` is documented as "the number of lists you would like to return" and the OP's code does turn `list(divide_list([1, 2], 3))` into `[[1], [2], []]` instead of your `[[1], [2]]`. Then again, "would like to" isn't "must", and their code might be buggy :-)

Comment: @KellyBundy is right. I didn't catch it the first time, but that first method would not result in the distribution I want. The second one is what I'm going for.

Comment: @GabeMorris yeah, I edited and added an answer... what I have may work differently than what you expect in cases where the length is smaller than `n`. In any case, Is till think the principle of just handling the iterator case applies. You can add a counter and check that the counter is < n to achieve a different behavior, which will give you *exactly* n sublists, whereas mine has *at least* n sublists, but won't produce empty ones just to reach n

Answer (score 1):

the problem is you don't take into account that you already consumed the iterator

```
>>> import itertools
>>> array_ = iter([12, 7, 9, 31, 13, 11, 7, 3])
>>> list(itertools.islice(array_,0,3))
[12, 7, 9]
>>> list(itertools.islice(array_,3,6)) #where are 31,13 and 11? you skipped them bacause, see below 
[7, 3]
>>> array_ = iter([12, 7, 9, 31, 13, 11, 7, 3])
>>> list(itertools.islice(array_,0,3))
[12, 7, 9]
>>> list(array_) #this is what remains in the iterator
[31, 13, 11, 7, 3]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank's to @KellyBundy, I was able to modify the code to get the expected results. I was not aware that `islice` was cutting the generator then shifting those values back to the beginning at index 0. I was treating it as if it left a null value at the indices that I cut off. Here is the modified code:

```
import itertools


def divide_list(array, n, gen_length=None):
    """
    :param array: some iterable that you wish to divide
    :param n: the number of lists you would like to return
    :param gen_length: The length of the generator if array is a generator. Not necessary for lists and tuples.
    :return: a generator of the divided list

    Example:
    In: list(divide_list([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 4))
    Out: [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7], [8, 9]]
    """
    if isinstance(array, (list, tuple)):
        floor, rem = divmod(len(array), n)

        items_index = (0, floor)
        for _ in range(n):
            prev, next_ = items_index[0], items_index[1] + 1 if rem > 0 else items_index[1]
            yield array[prev:next_]
            items_index = (next_, next_ + floor)
            rem -= 1
    else:
        floor, rem = divmod(gen_length, n)

        up_to = floor
        for _ in range(n):
            up_to = up_to + 1 if rem > 0 else up_to
            yield itertools.islice(array, up_to)
            up_to = floor
            rem -= 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    array_ = iter([12, 7, 9, 31, 13, 11, 7, 3])

    print('Generator:')
    print('----------')
    for value in divide_list(array_, 3, gen_length=8):
        print(list(value))

    print('')
    array_ = [12, 7, 9, 31, 13, 11, 7, 3]

    print('List:')
    print('-----')
    for value in divide_list(array_, 3):
        print(value)
```

This will output the expected result:

```
Generator:
----------
[12, 7, 9]
[31, 13, 11]
[7, 3]

List:
-----
[12, 7, 9]
[31, 13, 11]
[7, 3]
```